# DataSpell is using so much memory while I am not running any program

Tags: intellij-idea, dataspell

DataSpell is using so much memory while I am not running any program. After few seconds, the IDE gets killed automatically.

How can I turn off JCFF Helper from DataSpell? This stays even after the DataSpell is killed.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I suggest: use `Help | Contact Support...` from inside the DataSpell (`Ctrl+Shift+A` shortcut works even on Welcome screen when no project is opened) to contact JetBrains Support Team. If unable to do that or for whatever other reason it might be: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DS and submit the ticket there.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne for the suggestion. I uninstalled the IDE completely and installed it again. Now, there is working fine. If I find similar issue again, I will contact them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a very specific setup:

**Jupyter Notebook loaded from OneDrive**

I had a Jupyter Notebook opened which was located in my local OneDrive folder. Every time I started the DataSpell session with this tap opened, my ram increased until it was full.

**Solution:**

I opened another project where this tap is not loaded on startup and then opened all my files I needed again. I moved all the project files away from my OneDrive-Folder.
(I had more OneDrive and Jetbrains IDE related problems in the past)